# CodeMirror using jQuery .keyup on editor textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, codemirror, onkeyup

I want to getValue of Codemirror editor on keyup but it did not work.
Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5GJL/)

```
var mixedMode = {
        name: "htmlmixed",
        scriptTypes: [{matches: /\/x-handlebars-template|\/x-mustache/i,
                       mode: null},
                      {matches: /(text|application)\/(x-)?vb(a|script)/i,
                       mode: "vbscript"}]
      };
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("HTML"), {mode: mixedMode,lineNumbers: true  });

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#HTML").keyup(function(){
    html = editor.getValue();
    alert(html);
    });
});
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined`

Comment: @undefined I've linked CodeMirror to my webpage and the editor is working fine

Comment: The error is thrown in your jsfiddle. A demo that cannot reproduce the specified problem doesn't help at all.

Comment: @undefined sorry but The codeMirror editor isn't working because there's no way to link codeMirror library in jsfiddle online, suppose it's linked and working, could you help in keyup problem please.

Comment: No worries. Actually `jsfiddle` allows adding external CSS/JavaScript files in it's left panel, you could attach the needed files. And here is a CDN that hosts CodeMirror files http://cdnjs.com/libraries/codemirror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeMirror hides the `textarea` element, for listening to the events of the editor instance you can use the `on` method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    editor.on('change', function () {
        html = editor.getValue();
        alert(html);
    });
});
```

You can find the list of the supported events in the CodeMirror's manual.

http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#events

Answer (score 2):

```
editor.on("keyup", function(cm, event) {
    //only show hits for alpha characters
    if(!editor.state.completionActive && (event.keyCode > 65 && event.keyCode < 92)) {
        if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
        var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.clike, {completeSingle: false});
        }, 150);
    }
});
```

Replace 'CodeMirror.hint.clilke' with whichever hint mode you are using :)

Comment: I find that the `keyup` function preforms better than the `change` function.